# Ble peripheral are disconnected

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using ble peripheral tag. After scanning, I found identifier and name.

When I click on any cell, the desire peripherals are connected, and button in peripherals tag will detect and `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` methods are called on button click.

But when we are moving to another screen, the button will not detect and peripheral will disconnect.

Once the peripherals are connected, I want them always connected until app is not suspended.

The application is working on same screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing correct thing to show the peripherals in the screen but the connected methods you should not implement in the same screen. Better all the connection methods including `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` method you can implement in AppDelegate and use AppDelegate array to show the data in your main screen. This will solve your problem and it will work without any problem. If you still face any issue then please tell us and I will try to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer my proble is solve but one more issue when application in background after few minute peripheral will disconnect .